# How do I complete this C (assembly) character to hexadecimal and binary conversion code?

Tags: c

I need to write an assembly program in which I enter "abcd" and it gives me the hexadecimal and binary equivalents for each letter on it's own line. So I need to use the following in my code:

```
setmode(fileno(stdin), O_BINARY);
```

I have this, so far, but can't seem to compile it. What am I missing, and what can I change? Thank you.
So far, I have this:

```
    int main(void);
    {

       char c;
       int numChars = 0;

       setmode(fileno(stdin), O_BINARY);
       while(read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, ') > 0){
       ++numChars;
       }
       printf("%d\n", numChars);

       return 0;
       }
```

Comment: Does not compile with a major and obvious syntax error. Provide real code. If that's your real code, I frankly cannot retrace how you came up with that.

Comment: easy to see with the syntax highlighting that there is a string not being closed while `(read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, ') > 0){`

Comment: Try changing the `'` to a `1`.

Comment: Why binary mode? The hexadecimal digits `a..f` are **text** representations, for humans. But the question is not even clear about whether `"abcd"` is an ASCII string to be analysed, or a hexadecimal number. Please use an unambiguous example when you have `"abcd"` and "hexadecimal" in the same sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three problems:

No header files.  You need `stdio.h` for `printf` and `fileno`, and `io.h` for `read` and `setmode` (`setmode` is a Windows only function;  on Linux, you would include `unistd.h` for `read`).

This:

```
int main(void);
```

Is a function declaration, not a definition.  Get rid of the `;`:

```
int main(void);
```

Finally:

```
while(read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, ') > 0){
```

You have a `'` where there should be a value for the number of bytes to read.  This should be 1:

```
while(read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1) > 0){
```

Comment: It will also need the `fcntl.h` header file to define `O_BINARY`.

Comment: Thank you. That helped quite a bit.

Comment: @Jimmy Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and it is good, I just can't compile it. I'll go ahead and accept your answer, nonetheless. I'll figure it out.